# How do you ONLY get the value of the slider handle being moved with jQuery slider instead of both handles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update one field with the values from two handles, but only individually.  The Slider returns these 2 values in an array every time either handle slides, so my element always first gets updated with the first handle value and then the second handle value instead of ONLY the sliding handle's value.  How can I only get the value from the handle doing the sliding?

I tried putting an onChange function for the inputs being updated, but it wasn't working for some reason.

https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/6jm2prwL/5/

HTML

```
<div id="slider">

</div>


<div id="response">

</div>
```

JS

```
  jQuery('#slider').slider({

  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 1,
  values: [0, 100],
  slide: function(event, ui) {




    for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {

      theresult(ui.values[i]);

    }

  }

});

function theresult(theresult) {

  jQuery('#response').html(theresult);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of your for loop. Instead, call each result individually. So instead of this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
    theresult(ui.values[i]);
}
```

Do something like this:

```
alert(ui.values[0]);
alert(ui.values[1]);
```

Or, if you need them both to go to the "response" div, you can call them individually and concatenate them as a string like this (instead of either of the for loop or the two alerts above):

```
theresult(ui.values[0] + ',' + ui.values[1]);
```

Either of those will give you the individual values. You can save the individual values into variables and compare them with their old versions to see if they changed. Like this:

```
var min = 0;
var max = 100;
jQuery('#slider' ).slider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 1,
  values: [0, 100],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var newMin = ui.values[0];
    var newMax = ui.values[1];
    if (newMin != min) {
        theresult("Minimum changed: " + newMin);
      min = newMin;
    }
    else if (newMax != max) {
        theresult("Maximum changed: " + newMax);
      max = newMax;
    }
  }
});

function theresult(theresult) {
  jQuery('#response').html(jQuery('#response').html() + '<br>' + theresult);
}
```